# VNC can't control cursor in Kodi?

Tags: raspbian, kodi, vnc, mouse

I connect with VNC in HippoRemote for iOS to use my phone as a touchpad and keyboard. It works as expected on Raspbian's desktop but not when Kodi is launched. Neither mouse nor keyboard events from VNC seem to reach it. Why?

Can it be made to work?

Answer (score 1):

Kodi is not an x-windows based app, so VNC will not work with it

[source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=102359)

Comment: I couldn't find any mentions of keyboard or mouse in your source.

Comment: The desktop (X) and Kodi (framebuffer) use different Dispmanx layers. Forums suggest you might try dispmanx_vnc to try and set up a VNC server from the Kodi layer. (https://github.com/hanzelpeter/dispmanx_vnc) tutorial at (https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/howto-install-a-vnc-server-on-the-raspberry-pi/1517)

Comment: Ok, I know nothing about dispmanx. Those layers affect keyboard and mouse events too, if I understand you correctly?